# simply change suffix using .bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filenames

I just need to rename sequence of files from, say ######.avi to ###two.avi using .bat
So I need to remove 3 last symbols before extension and change them into "two". I found a solution for prefix changing,

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.avi) do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof
:rename
ren %fname% two%fname:~3%
goto :eof
```

but nothing on suffix.
Thanks in advance.

***UPD.***
Thanx man! That's the solution. With I could head you up with +1 rep, but I can't. (don't have the 15 rep required) 
Also, to not write so much, this can be done in shorter text:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.avi) do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
:renameFile
ren %fname% %fname:~0,3%two.avi
```

Comment: The rename will fail if the name contains a space, `^` or `&` unless the quotes are used.

Comment: If all original files have same lenght names (ie, six characters), this simpler method also works: `REN ??????.AVI ???TWO.AVI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, you just need the ~n expansion modifier to get the base name without the extension. It works with both FOR variables as well as CALL parameters. I would change the name of your :rename routine so that it cannot be confused with the RENAME command).

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.avi) do (set fname=%%~ni) & call :renameFile
goto :eof
:renameFile
ren "%fname%.avi" "%fname:~0,-3%two.avi"
goto :eof
```

If you activate delayed expansion, you don't need the subroutine. I toggle delayed expansion within the loop so that a file name with `!` is not corrupted during the assignment of fname.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.avi) do (
  set fname=%%~ni
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!fname!.avi" "!fname:~0,-3!two.avi"
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: +1: That's how I would have done it, except I didn't know about "is not corrupted during the assignment of fname" - learn something new about CMD.EXE every day ;-)